# Meteor-React-Ionic app crashing even though code is supposedly right

Tags: mobile, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm doing the [Meteor-React-Ionic mobile app development walkthrough](https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-react-ionic-mobile-app-part-1-the-basic-template-9355ebf3397f#.en13un6cp). This question is perhaps best suited for someone who has read this article.

Wrote the code exactly as given, yet when I run the app at the end of the first article, I keep getting "your app is crashing" and "exited at code: 8."

Here's the log as shown on the browser:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log. 

/Users/hmm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.jggotu++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Invariant Violation: You cannot use <HistoryLocation> without a DOM
    at invariant (packages/node_modules/react/lib/invariant.js:42:1)
    at createRouter (lib/node_modules/react-router/lib/createRouter.js:131:1)
    at Object.runRouter [as run] (lib/node_modules/react-router/lib/runRouter.js:40:1)
    at ./router.jsx:11:15
    at /Users/hmm/hmmmm/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:229:5
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Any help with figuring out where I went wrong and what I should do would be much appreciated. Code I wrote are exactly the same as the ones given in the article (hence my confusion).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to change the order of the folders.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I'm having a similar error and I can't seem to resolve it.

Comment: In my case, there was a child folder that needed to be a parent folder.